# How do I find the torrent file for a current download?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, utorrent

I've had something hanging on utorrent for a few days so I thought I would update the trackers. But I cannot seem to find the actual `.torrent` file for that download. I've looked through the tabs and checked the download's `Properties` sheet but it doesn't seem to be there.

Curiously I have also had a quick scan through Spotlight results for a search for the file extension but there doesn't seem to be a matching one. The download is still running and some of the original trackers are no longer working, but most are so I *can't* have accidentally deleted it - or can I ...?

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are stored in `~/Library/Application Support/uTorrent/`. It's excluded from normal Spotlight results, but you can still search for the torrent files with mdfind:

```
mdfind kMDItemFSName=*.torrent
mdfind kMDItemContentType=org.bittorrent.torrent
```

Transmission stores .torrent files in `~/Library/Application Support/Transmission/Torrents/`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you open a .torrent file in a bit client it should not matter whether the torrent file is deleted from your filesystem or not. From what I understand, since the torrent is still active, you should be able to do the following:

Go to the 'Info' tab for the download and copy the hash value.
Search for the value on a site such as http://torrentz.eu/.
Get the uTorrent compatible tracker list (available towards the bottom of the page).
Update trackers herewith.

Alternatively, you could get the torrent file instead of the tracker list from the site as well.